# Cross validation for kernel regression

Tags: kernel-trick, ridge-regression

I've been reading about the Kernel trick, where we we can obtain a prediction by calculating: $\hat{y} = y(K(x,x)+\lambda I_n)^{−1} K(x,\hat{x})$, where $K(x,z) = (1+xz)^p$. If I want to tune the parameters $p$ and $\lambda$, how do I use cross-validation here? My understanding is that for CV we normally use a train split to train the model, and then test the model on the test split. How do we do that here, as we are not fitting a model/parameters, but instead directly computing the prediction?

Comment: I don't understand the distinction that you're making between ordinary train-test CV splits and the train-test splits here. If you split your data, and measure some figure of merit on the hold-out data, it seems to be exactly like the ordinary train-test CV.

Comment: @Sycorax yes I'm trying to do ordinary train-test CV, but I don't understand what 'training' needs to be done here, as no parameters are fitted.

Comment: The purpose of the train-test split has more to do with measuring how a model performs on out-of-sample data than it does with parameter estimation. In a certain sense, once the data are known and the model hyper-parameters are fixed, the model coefficients must be fixed at their optimal values (given the data, the model, and the hyper-parameters). Consider an OLS with a polynomial basis of order $k$. You can choose a large $k$ and interpolate the data, but this may predict poorly. Likewise the $p$ and $\lambda$ in your kernel problem.